# How can Django be configured not to default fields to not null?

Tags: django, django-models, model, default, notnull

How can Django be configured not to default fields to not null?

Django defaults all fields created to NOT NULL. Can it be configured to do the opposite, except in the obvious case of key fields?

Comment: I am looking for an option built into django itself that can be applied globally or per project. In this case it doesn't seem to exist. How do I mark the responses in this case? Do I simply mark the helpful ones even if they are not what I wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null=True, blank=True`, [docs, docs, docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

Comment: I mean whether it is possible for it to default to null=True without making it explicit in the model

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit, @vfclists.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But my text editor macros do add null=True, blank=True by default. Maybe that's what you need.